# Is it possible to distinguish in a trigger if a create new record is started from a related list or from the object

Tags: apex, trigger, lookup, related-list, create-records

I have a requirement to pre-fill some fields when a record is created from a related list. These requirements are different when created from the object itself. Is there a way that I can capture this difference in a before trigger?

Comment: Setting aside the use of a list button, I'd think that using the standard 'new' button on a related list would cause the record to have its relationship field populated before getting into the triggers. I'll have to test that out a bit later.

Comment: The relationship field could be a mandatory lookup or could be a master detail, in which case it has to already be populated before the trigger is invoked (a failure to provide the value would cause a missing required field validation before the trigger is called IIRC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no available data that conclusively tells you how the record creation was initiated.